# incompatible types in assignment of 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' to

Tags: c++, arrays, maps, associative

```
int main()
{

std::string my_string= "16657";
std::map<std::string, std::string[2]> m_msg_int;
std::string arrId[2];
arrId[0] = "ABC";
arrId[1] = "XYZ/CDE";
m_msg_int[my_string] = arrId[2];
std::cout<<"MSGID"<<msgId[0]<<endl;

 }
```

incompatible types in assignment of ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string}’ to ‘std::map, std::basic_string [2]>::mapped_type {aka std::basic_string [2]}’

Comment: Yes, `m_msg_int[my_string]` is an array of two strings, and `arrId[2]` would have been one string if it had existed. You need a different approach, and you need to study some more about arrays in your favourite C++ book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In line

```
m_msg_int[my_string] = arrId[2];
```

you are accessing the array `arrId` out of bounds because it has size of 2 and reading `arrId[2]` causes undefined behavior. Even if you wouldn't access out of bounds

```
m_msg_int[my_string]
```

is a reference to an array of strings and

```
arrId[2]
```

is a string. Probably you are trying to assign

```
m_msg_int[my_string] = arrId;
```

but in C++ you can't assign a basic array to a basic array. You should use std::array for this

```
#include <array>
#include <map>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string my_string= "16657";
    std::map<std::string, std::array<std::string, 2>> m_msg_int;
    std::array<std::string, 2> arrId;
    arrId[0] = "ABC";
    arrId[1] = "XYZ/CDE";
    m_msg_int[my_string] = arrId;
    //std::cout<<"MSGID"<<msgId[0]<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You assign a `std::string` to a array of `std::string`.

```
m_msg_int[my_string] = arrId;
```

Now we assign a array of `std::string` to our map.

**NOTE**: Array index range is `n` to `n-1`. And you can't do this:

```
m_msg_int[my_string] = arrId[2];
```

Because `arrId` have 2 element, But index `2` means third element.

Comment: `m_msg_int[my_string] = arrId;` is not allowed https://wandbox.org/permlink/iODN0dBejDRNyrYV